# skip all the header lines in a csv or text data file in PYTHON

Tags: python, csv

I have big data set which is essentially multiple files appended together. the data file has numerous header lines. Except the header line in row 1, I would like to skip all the headerline and just read data from the data file.

How can I do it in python? a simple example would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the header line looks like (which it sounds like you do), you can literally just pass over it in the for loop by ignoring it.

```
myfile = open("data.txt")
header = next(myfile) # assume the first line is header
for line in myfile:
   if line == header: continue
   # process non-header line
```

Comment: Considering the limited information you provided I would say this is the best option. You could also use a RegExp to check if the line matches a certain pattern, and then skip it.